Montonicity of incomplete beta function
Consider the function $f(x) = \log( \beta(x,\alpha, \beta) / x^{\alpha} )$ where $\beta(x,\alpha, \beta)$ is the incomplete beta function
$$
\beta(x,\alpha, \beta) = \int_{t=0}^x t^{\alpha-1} (1-t)^{\beta - 1} \ dt
$$
It appears that when $\beta \in [0,1]$, the function $f$ is absolutely monotonic, i.e. all derivatives of $f$ are positive.
Is there any reference or proof of this?

My go-to reference for most functions is K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, An Atlas of Functions, $2^{nd}$  Ed., Springer . Chapter 58 covers the Incomplete Beta Function.
